# Div не хочет вставать под Div

Tags: css, html

Начинающий в верстке, так что сильно не ругайте :) Вывожу данные из бд в список, под списком хочу поставить `div`, но он встает на список.

Вот скрипт в котором генерится html

```
 <?php
$servername = ":)";
$username = ":)";
$password = ":)";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$conn -> query("USE game");
$conn -> set_charset("utf8");
if ($conn -> connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$users = $conn -> query("SELECT * FROM `game` . `players`");
echo "<html><head><title>Аккаунты</title><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"/><meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#711BCB\"/><link href=\"styles.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"></head><body><div id=\"header\"><div id=\"headercontent\"><h1>Аккаунты</h1></div></div>";
echo "<div id=\"wrapper\"><div id=\"list4\"><ul>";
while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"h\"><strong>$user[name]</strong></a></li>";
}
echo "</ul></div>";
echo "<div id=\"add\"><a href=\"#\"><h2>Добавить аккаунт...</h2></a></div></div>";
echo "</body></html>";
$conn -> close();
    ?>
```

CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
}

#wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;

    }

#add {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    align: center;
    left: 15%;
    didpay: inline-block;
    background-color:#711BCB;
}

#add h2 {
    padding:30px;
    margin: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Nova Flat', Nova Cut, Nova Oval;
}

#list4 {
     width: 100%;
}
#list4 ul {
    list-style: none;
    height: 50px;
}
#list4 ul li { }
#list4 ul li a { 
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000; 
background-color:#FFFFFF;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-bottom-color:#CCCCCC; 
border-right-style:solid;
border-right-width:1px;
border-right-color:#CCCCCC; 
border-left-style:solid;
border-left-width:1px;
border-left-color:#CCCCCC; 
border-top-style:solid;
border-top-width:1px;
border-top-color:#CCCCCC; 
padding:30px;
margin:30px;
cursor:pointer;
}
#list4 ul li a strong {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Nova Flat', Nova Cut, Nova Oval;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#header {
    background-color: #711BCB;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#header h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 60px;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Nova Flat', Nova Cut, Nova Oval;
}
#headercontent {
      position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    }
```

Скрин

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: абсолютное позиционирование...

Comment: @DNS, ох, извините, видимо это легко, но как? Добавить диву `wrapper` строку `position: absolute`?

Comment: наоборот, попробуйте адд поставить релатив. Экспериментируйте, код большой, сразу все не разберешь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посоветую, пользоваться bootstrap, дает хороший старт + экономия вашего времени. Удачи в верстке. Также почитайте про шаблонизаторы и MVC, выводить весь html, через echo - дорого. 
Я тоже новичок, но не судите, да не судимы будете)) 
Попробуйте вот так вот:

```
    //db.php

<?php
$db = new db();
  class db { //желательно сделать его абстрактным

    privat $servername = ":)";
    privat $username = ":)";
    privat $password = ":)";

    public function __construct() {
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
      $conn -> query("USE game");
      $conn -> set_charset("utf8");
      if ($conn -> connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
      }
    }

    public function q ($path) {
        return $conn -> query(".$path.");
    }

    public function x () {
        return $conn -> close();;
    } 

  }
?>

//controller.php

<?php 

class App {

  function __autoload () {

    require_once './db.php';
    include_once './wiev.php';

  }

  public function users($query) {
      return $user = $db->$q(".$query.");
  }

}


?>

//index.php
<?php
       require_once __DIR__ . 'controller.php';

       $app = new App();
       $users = $app->users('>> your sql here <<.');
       $db->$x;

?>

//wiev.php

<html>
<head><title>Аккаунты</title>
  <meta charset=\"UTF-8\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"/>
  <meta name=\"theme-color\" content=\"#711BCB\"/><link href=\"styles.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
</head>
<body>
  <div id=\"header\">
    <div id=\"headercontent\">
      <h1>Аккаунты</h1>
    </div>
  </div>";
<div id=\"wrapper\"><div id=\"list4\">
  <ul>
      <?php
      while($user = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
          echo "<li><a href=\"h\"><strong>$user[name]</strong></a></li>";
      }
      ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id=\"add\"><a href=\"#\"><h2>Добавить аккаунт...</h2></a></div></div>";
</body></html>
```